# How to change “Press ESC to exit fullscreen”

Tags: java, javafx

How can I use **setFullScreenExitHint** ?

Because :   Cannot resolve method 'setFullScreenExitHint'

Have you any better way like setFullScreen ??

*JDK: jdk1.8.0_171*

```
package game;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/login.fxml"));
    Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    Scene scene = new Scene(parent, screenBounds.getWidth(), 
    screenBounds.getHeight());
    primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked perfectly for me:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/login.fxml"));
    Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    Scene scene = new Scene(parent, screenBounds.getWidth(), 
    screenBounds.getHeight());
    primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setFullScreenExitHint("hello");
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

It's in JavaFX 8 Documentation: [Stage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html)

If you set the exit key combination to `KeyCombination.NO_MATCH` the pop-up message will be disabled completely.